# Not able to get response from PATCH API call for webservice in Swift 3 by Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, patch

I am trying to make call by PATCH method. I am using Alamofire library for making networking calls. For GET/POST its working fine, but while trying to make call PATCH getting following errors.

```
ResponseSerializationFailed
Code 3840 from network
```

I am calling request like by following

```
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .patch, parameters: params as? [String:Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

        requestVC.removeLoader()
        switch (response.result) {
        case .success:
            if response.result.value != nil{
                completionHandler (response.result.value)
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            failureHandler (error as NSError?)
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: The call is made, but the response you are getting is not json.

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: Check (with curl for instance) what the response is from the server. If you set a breakpoint in the failure case, you can use the debugger to inspect the response. `po String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8)`

Answer (score 0):

Its happening due to some internal issue for calling api request. Fixed.